# NameError: name 'DSAHeapEntry' is not defined

Tags: python, algorithm, ubuntu, terminal

```
import heapsort

# Create an array of DSAHeapEntry objects and populate it with values
arr = [DSAHeapEntry(5), DSAHeapEntry(3), DSAHeapEntry(8), DSAHeapEntry(1), DSAHeapEntry(2)]

# Sort the array using heap sort
heapSort(arr)

# Print the sorted array
for entry in arr:
    print(entry.value)
```

This is the test code that I have written to implement the following code:

```
    class DSAHeapEntry:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def heapSort(arr):
    n = len(arr)

    # Build a max heap
    for i in range(n // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
        heapify(arr, n, i)

    # Extract elements from the heap in descending order
    for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        arr[0], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[0]
        heapify(arr, i, 0)

def heapify(arr, n, i):
    largest = i
    left = 2 * i + 1
    right = 2 * i + 2

    if left < n and arr[left].value > arr[largest].value:
        largest = left

    if right < n and arr[right].value > arr[largest].value:
        largest = right

    if largest != i:
        arr[i], arr[largest] = arr[largest], arr[i]
        heapify(arr, n, largest)
```

Even though I import this code into the test implementation, I keep getting a NameError saying that DSAHeapEntry hasn't been defined. How do I fix this?

Comment: `from heapsort import DSAHeap, heapSort` ...

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to to fix this

1. using heapsort.function() write code as below

```
import heapsort

arr = [ heapsort.DSAHeapEntry(5), heapsort.DSAHeapEntry(3),heapsort.DSAHeapEntry(8),heapsort.DSAHeapEntry(1), heapsort.DSAHeapEntry(2)]

heapsort.heapSort(arr)

for entry in arr:
    print(entry.value)
```

2. import only required functions

```
from heapsort import DSAHeapEntry,heapSort
    
arr = [ DSAHeapEntry(5), DSAHeapEntry(3), DSAHeapEntry(8),
        DSAHeapEntry(1), DSAHeapEntry(2)]
    
heapSort(arr)
    
for entry in arr:
    print(entry.value)
```

3. import all from heapsort write code as follows

```
from heapsort import *
    
arr = [ DSAHeapEntry(5), DSAHeapEntry(3), DSAHeapEntry(8),
        DSAHeapEntry(1), DSAHeapEntry(2)]
    
heapSort(arr)
    
for entry in arr:
    print(entry.value)
```

All methods worked for me but in case it doesn't work please make sure there is `__init__`.py file in the directory where heapsort file is if not create a same blank file

also there is extra tab before

```
class DSAHeapEntry:
```

*i think it just a mistake in stackoverflow but if there are errors in heapsort.py then also it wont work*

hope this helps.